# How to run Detox tests on AWS Device Farm?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, automated-tests, detox

I have automated UI tests for React Native using Detox and they run fine on my local machine. I want to use AWS Device Farm service to run parallel tests in the cloud. AWS announced that they already added support for Detox.

However, when I configure my test on Device Farm, it does not show me option for Detox, but only for "Appium Node.js".

I expect for the tests to at least run, and see the app at least opening in the video artifacts. But instead, I get all failed and no activity in the video.

Answer (score 6):

Getting Detox to work on Device Farm would take a concentrated effort on our customer’s part, potentially several full weeks of time, with no guarantee of success. As noted here (https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/95), it can be difficult getting Detox tests to run on real devices in the first place. Additionally, it’s possible that the Xcode libraries required by Detox won’t be available on the iOS device farm host.

Finally, getting Detox to use pre-existing apps on the device that we pre-sign using the device farm signature could introduce another impossible hurdle.